# MySQL - Get product amounts

Tags: mysql, sql

In mySql, I need to find products with amounts.

This is not the problem and easy. (**This is only a example**)

```
ProductID,Name,Ammount 
1,PRODUCT1,5
```

But i have lot of properties for this product. (not only color and size)

```
PropertiID,Name
1,black
2,yellow
3,red
4,blue
5,S
6,M
7,L
8,XL
```

This give me a lot of combinations for product with the ID 1 like
As example:

```
PRODUCT1,black,S
PRODUCT1,red,XL
PRODUCT1,red,L
PRODUCT1,red,M
...
```

I must save the ammount of each combination.

```
PRODUCT1,black,S,4
PRODUCT1,red,XL,6
PRODUCT1,red,L,2
PRODUCT1,red,M,0
...
```

The problem is the amount.
Where can i save the amount.
I have 1 line of 1 product and some combinations with properties related to the products.

Thanks for help 
    Andy

Comment: How are the `products` and `properties` tables related? There's no foreign key between them.

Comment: There are now no relations between the tables. Because how i can mix the product and the properties (more than 1).  Where i save the Ammount. Must i make a helping table between `Product` and `Properties` ? A `Product_Properties` table. Then i can make relations. Then i save the `ProductID`, the `PropertiesID` and the `Ammount` in the `Product_Properties` table. But this is not a nice Table..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names of the tables as `product` and `property`, and `property` has a reference for product id, below query should work:

```
select p.productId, amount, group_concat(pr.name)
from product p join property pr on p.productId = pr.productId
group by p.productId, amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `ProductProperties` table to relate the two tables. Then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the properties.

```
SELECT p.productID, p.amount, GROUP_CONCAT(pr.name) AS properties
FROM Product AS p
JOIN ProductProperties AS pp ON p.productID = pp.productID
JOIN Property AS pr ON pr.PropertyID = pp.PropertyID
GROUP BY p.productID
```

Comment: But then i have the `p.amount` in the `Product` table for 1 product. But i have lot of combinations for PRODUCT1 with diffrent amount of the `PRODUCT1` with diffrent combinations.  I dont know where i save the `amount`. I cant save it in the `Product` table, because i have one line per product and lot of combinations with the `Propertys` .... with my data i have i have over 80 combinations in one product. And i have about 300 products there are 24000 products if i save it in the product table with combinations. So i have my 300 products in product table and my 41 propertys.

Comment: Each row of `Product` is an instance of the product with a specific set of properties. You can have `1,PRODUCT1,4` and `2,PRODUCT1,6` in the `Product` table. Then the `ProductProperty` table would indicate that `ProductID = 1` has properties `black` and `S`, while `ProductID = 2` has properties `red` and `XL`.

Comment: Yes ok this is clear. But then must the user enter 80 products with combinations for 1 product. And in the GUI he have over 24000 products.

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid that. If there are different amounts for each combination of properties, someone has to enter each one somewhere.

Comment: Maybe i have a solution for this. If i break down the properties table, and make entrys like `Black XL` `Blue S`. Then i can save the ammount in the ProductProperties table.  `ProductID,PropertyID,Amount`   mean product id 1 and property 1 is `Product1,Black XL` .. only as example.  I try it tomorrow, now is bedtime here HEHE ;)  Thanks for input Barmar